# Do uniform values remain in GLSL shader if unbound?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am writing a program that uses two different shaders for different primitives. My question is: if I bind a program, send it uniform variables, then use another shader program and come back to the first one, will the passed uniform values remain? Here is some pseudocode:

```
glUseProgram(shader1);
glUniform(shader1,...);
//stuff

for(elements in a list) {
    if(element.type = 1) {
        glUseProgram(shader2);
        element.draw();
    } else {
        glUseProgram(shader1); //Here, do the uniforms from above remain, if shader2 was bound before?
        element.draw();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, uniforms are specific to a program, and will be persistent if you unbind and rebind it.

Also, if you want, you could easily verify this yourself in that sample with [glGetUniform](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetUniform.xml).

From the [OpenGL 4.1 Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec41.core.20100725.pdf):

> #### 2.11.7 Uniform Variables
>
> ... Uniforms are program object-specific state. They retain their values once loaded, and their values are restored whenever a program object is used, as long as the program object has not been re-linked. ...

Comment: Do you happen to have an official source on this?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about glGetUniform, very useful.

Comment: I want to know if this applies to attribute also. I mean if you enable some attributes glEnableVertexAttribArray and then unbind/rebind the shader, will the vertex attribute also remain and I can just call the draw ?

Comment: @PankajBansal Vertex attributes are tracked by the bound vertex array object, not the shader program. Shader programs and VAOs are not directly related. You must bind both the correct shader program and VAO before rendering. For an intro to VAO, see: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object