# Does uniforms set and vertex attributes values remain when shader is unbound

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

I am want to know if the uniform and vertex attribute variable values remain if the shader program is unbound and then rebound

Basically I want to ask this question [Do uniform values remain in GLSL shader if unbound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857602/do-uniform-values-remain-in-glsl-shader-if-unbound). But I want to know if this applies to both uniforms and attribure variables?

If I do this

```
    glUseProgram(shader1);
    // Now set uniforms.
    glUniform4fv(m_uniforms[COLOR_HANDLE], 1, color.AsFloat());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(m_uniforms[MVP_HANDLE], 1, false, matrix);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferIndex);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_attributes[POSITION_HANDLE1]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_attributes[POSITION_HANDLE2]);

    glVertexAttribPointer(m_attributes[POSITION_HANDLE], 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
```

Now save the current program, vao, vbo binded. 
Then use second program

```
    glUseProgram(shader2);
    //bind some new vao, vbo, set some uniform, vertex attribute variable.
    element.draw();
```

Then again use the first shader program. Rebind the vbo, vao

```
    glUseProgram(shader1); //Here, do the uniforms and attributes set in first shader program remain?
    element.draw();
```

Does this mean that complete state is restored and draw calls will work. I think this should work if the uniforms and attribute values are retained. So when I restore the client program with glUseProgram, all uniforms and attributes set by client will be restored.

If not, then how can I save complete state. Onething is client has to set them again. but if that is not an option, what is other way around. How can I save the full state and restore it later. Is it even possible ?

PS: I need to do it for opengl 2.0, opengl 3.2+, opengl es 2.0, opengles 3.0

Comment: "*Now if I restore the program and vbo, vao being used, does that mean that complete state is restored and client can go ahead and make draw calls.*" What do you mean by "restore it"? Restore it where? Are you talking about rebinding the current VAO and program, or are you talking about building new objects with the same state as the old ones?

Comment: I mean I will use glUseProgram with saved program, then rebind the vao and vbo.

Comment: Are you thinking about creating something like a push/pop state on the program? So the user of your module would be able to push the current state which would save all the current settings/calls on the program, then the user could modify the calls, do some additional work and call pop to restore everything to a previous state? You can do this by creating a higher level of tool where user would only call your methods and you would be able to save the values. Still this is dangerous for cases such as if the user sets a pointer to vertex data from the CPU memory or even worse a stack...

Comment: Basically what I want to ask is this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857602/do-uniform-values-remain-in-glsl-shader-if-unbound
But in my case I want to know if both uniforms and attributes values remain or not. I can see that uniforms remain, but what about attributes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Uniforms**

Uniforms are part of the shader program object. Thus they keep saved even when the program object is unbound. The [OpenGL 4.5 Specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf) says to this:

> 7.6 Uniform Variables
>
> Uniforms in the default uniform block, except for subroutine uniforms, are
> program object-specific state. They retain their values once loaded, and their values
> are restored whenever a program object is used, as long as the program object has
> not been re-linked.

**Attributes**

Attribute bindings are part of the VAO state. When no VAO is bound then the default VAO is used (which is btw. not allowed in Core Profile). When using VAOs, restoring attribute bindings is quite simple since it is sufficient to rebind the VAO. In the other case, I would have a look at the "Associated Gets" section [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml).

Comment: so if I am not using vao, I will have to save state state for all vertex attribute location.
1. Do I have to change save information for all locations or just the once I am changing. Lets say there are 128 attribute locations allowed, but I am only changing 3, I will save info only for 3 or for all 128

2. The info I have to store is
Is array location enabled, size, stride, type, normalized flag. Also I will have to see if I am using a vbo for this or directly giving a vertex array pointer from cpu.  I there anythng else I will have to save