# OO architecture for simple shader-based GL program

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, shader

I'm designing an OO program (in C++) which deals with moderately-simple graphics implemented with OpenGL. I've written a couple of vertex shader programs for my `Drawable` objects to use. In addition, I've encapsulated shader management (compilation, linking and usage) in a `Shader` class.

My question is, since all my classes will be rendering visual objects using this small set of shaders and they all have a pointer to a `Shader` object, does it make sense to provide a **common reference** for all of them to use, so that it would avoid having "the same" shader code compiled more than once?

If so, why? Is it really important to prevent duplication of shader code? (My program will likely have thousands of independent visual elements that need to be rendered together). I'm new to OpenGL and performance/efficiency issues are still very obscure to me...

**EDIT:** Moreover, I wonder what will then happen with my shader uniforms; will they be shared as well? How's that supposed to allow me to, e.g. rotate my elements at a different rate? Is it better to write element-uniforms (i.e. the model matrix) every time I want to draw each element, than to have replicated shader code?

Comment: You should definitely not duplicate shaders. The only thing that has to be duplicated is the VAO and the VBOs. But since you already said that Drawable has a pointer to Shader, I don't see any reason why multiple Drawables shouldn't point to the same shader object.

Comment: Would the fact that each element requires its independent (i.e. not shared) model matrix? Or are the values of uniforms part of the VAO?

Comment: Uniforms are part of the shader. But updating a uniform variable in a shader is way faster than switch the shader.

Answer (score 1):

I would wager that in most if not all OpenGL implementations, compiling and linking the same shader multiple times would result in multiple copies of the shader binaries and space for uniforms, etc. Calling glUseProgram to switch between your duplicate copies will still cause a state change, despite the same code being run on your GPU cores before and after the call. With a sufficiently complex enough scene, you'll probably be switching textures as well so there will be a state change anyways.

It may not be your bottleneck, but it certainly is wasteful. A good pattern for static content like shaders and textures is to have one or more `Manager` classes (`AssetManager`, `TextureManager`, etc.) that will lazy-load (or pre-load) all of your assets and give you a shared pointer (or some other memory-management strategy) when you ask for it, typically by some string ID.

**About the edit:**

Yes, your uniforms will be shared and will also [remain loaded after you unbind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857631/1122135). This is the preferred way to do it because [updating a uniform is more than an order of magnitude faster than binding a new shader](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/37/what-is-the-cost-of-changing-state). You would just set the model matrix uniforms for every new object but keep the same shader.

Uniforms are stored with the shader, so switching shaders means loading in all of the uniforms anyways.

Comment: As I've just mentioned in the (recently edited) question, would uniforms be shared if I use a single shared `Shader` reference?

Comment: Updated my answer